# How can I increase the size of a node proportional to the number of indegrees in Gephi?

Tags: math, visualization, data-visualization, graph-visualization, gephi

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve. It is quite simple and some Gephi experts could help me out. I want the node size to increase to the proportional of indegrees towards that node. This is obviously a directed graph as you might have figured.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you expect, this is a commong Gephi ranking feature.

- Go to ranking dock (normally at the top-left of the UI coupled with partition dock), you can find screenshots and details at http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/GUI_Description
- chose the node tab in order to rank by node, chose the "red diamond" icon, in order to rank by size.
- In the dropdown menu chose InDegree as rank parameter. (if you don't see the indegree parameter see further on this answer).
- Set min size and max size as you wish,
- select the range of the InDegree values to consider (usually the complete range).
- If you want to increase the size proportionally to indegree in a linear way, leave the spline as default, otherwise you can curve the correlation.

That's it, push apply and you'll have it.

If you don't see the InDegree parameter you need to calculate it before. To do this:

- focus on the statistics dock (bottom-right of the GUI).
- run the Avarege Degree statistic (which - if your network is directed - calculates degree, indegree and outdegree).
- to be shure your network is directed, focus on the context dock (upper-right of the UI). It says number of nodes, number of edges, and type of graph (directed or undirected).
- after calculating the degrees values, gephi associates them to the nodes and you can use them as ranking parameters.

Comment: Thank you Miro. If I run into any trouble I will come back.:)

Comment: Hey Miro, apprantely my indegree and outdegree are inversed, how do I tell Gephi that the outdegree column is supposed to be the indegree one?

Comment: Yes, dis is related to the direction of edges of your directed graph. I am not sure, but I think there isn't a quick function to invert direction of edges in gephi. I posted a comment in this gephi [forum](http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=524) (waiting to be approved). What you can do, anyway, is to invert your data. How is your data? Did you import it in gephi?

Comment: Hey, do you know how to convert normal characters into unicode in gephi. I have some ascii chars that need to be properly encoded into unicode?

Comment: I don't know.
A reply in gephi forum by Eduardo:

> «Sorry, this is not implemented (it's still considered for implementation) since it wasn't critical or very needed».

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up two comments: 1) I don't know about unicode stuff in gephi and 2) speaking of inverting edges direction, in the [forum topic](http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=524) I mentioned 4 comments before, my question has been accepted and Eduardo posted an answer: funcion «not implemented (it's still considered for implementation)». I guess the only thing you can do is to invert your raw data (ex. if you use an edges table in excel, you should invert source and target columns).